# Tailwindcss class not taking effect when added with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I added a tailwindcss class to my content div using javascript. It is added but doesn't take effect unless I add that class manually to the div and then remove it.

I made a fixed header using Tailwind CSS and needed to add margin to the main content div equal to the height of the header.
The height of the header changes depending on the screen size so I used Javascript for changing the margin equal to the header's height.
The class is applied to the div but it doesn't take effect.
Here's my code:
[main content html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Ke5.png)
Javascript:
[Javascript for adding the margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bc1V.png)
As you can see in the inspect the margin class 'mt-[88px]' is added but the main-content div has no margin at all.
[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhgVS.png)
It works If I add the margin manually once and then remove it but I don't know why it doesn't work from the get-go.
Even if I add the margin manually once I have to do it for each header height. For instance it's 88px on larger screens so I add mt-[88px] and then just remove it and add mt-[104px] for smaller screens and then remove the class.
My tailwindcss config file:
[tailwind.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO9On.png)

Comment: that's not the problem. I have added other classes and they are working just fine. Javascript is working on this one as well but it

Comment: it's not taking effect for some reason unless i manually add and remove the class once.

Comment: Done. I have uploaded image of my config file.

Comment: I see I didn't notice js image. Check [this page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)

Comment: Please insert the code into your question, not as picture for readability.